# Why does the XName equality operator appear to refer to itself?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, equality

I was wondering how equality is defined for XName, and noticed that the equality operator appears to refer to itself (when viewing the decompiled C# using ILSpy 2.4.0.1963)

```
public static bool operator ==(XName left, XName right)
{
    return left == right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in your decompiler.

It's actually casting both operands to `object` to compare by reference.

See the [actual source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,160):

```
    // The overloads of == and != are included to enable comparisons between
    // XName and string (e.g. element.Name == "foo"). C#'s predefined reference
    // equality operators require one operand to be convertible to the type of
    // the other through reference conversions only and do not consider the
    // implicit conversion from string to XName.

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a value indicating whether two instances of <see cref="XName"/> are equal.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="left">The first XName to compare.</param>
    /// <param name="right">The second XName to compare.</param>
    /// <returns>true if left and right are equal; otherwise false.</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This overload is included to enable the comparison between
    /// an instance of XName and string.
    /// </remarks>
    public static bool operator ==(XName left, XName right) {
        return (object)left == (object)right;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It appears that XName is immutable, i.e. two XName(s) created with the same name are actually the same object; hence it makes sense to use reference equality as fast equality test.

Comment: @redcalx: That's not what immutability means (although immutability is a prerequisite for that).  An immutable class can still have two different instances with the same value.  This works because `XName` is pooled (or interned).